# get duplicate row but more strictly

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm selecting a duplicate row via the query below:

```
SELECT name, day, COUNT(name)
FROM filters
WHERE BOX = '1' OR BOX = '2' AND day = '2021-07-23'
GROUP BY name,day HAVING COUNT(name)>1;
```

Everything is fine, but I want to make it more strictly. I want to get the duplicate rows if these query results do exist in my **WHERE** conditions.

For example, if this query returns me a result that's named (**X2**), that means that **X2.BOX** is equal to '1' or '2' and it's day should be '2021-07-23';

At the moment when the results are returned by the query, and none have met the **WHERE** conditions, I want to tell the query to return me nothing or null or etc...

Comment: Adding sample data to your question would help others understand it better.

Comment: Use parentheses: `WHERE (BOX = '1' OR BOX = '2') AND day = '2021-07-23'`

Comment: I concur with forpas; you seem to be saying that the db is returning you results that are not for 2021-07-23' but that's because you haven't put the OR in parentheses so you're getting all the box=1, plus the box=2 from 2021-07-23

Comment: @forpas i added parentheses but nothing changed...

Comment: Nothing changed compared to what? You did not post any sample data and your expected results.

Comment: @CaiusJard i tried it now. nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Could you change this

```
WHERE BOX = '1' OR BOX = '2' AND day = '2021-07-23'
```

to

```
WHERE BOX in ('1','2') AND day = '2021-07-23'
```

I may be misunderstanding though, if you can post some sample output vs expected results that would be helpful

Comment: `SELECT name, day, COUNT(name) FROM filters WHERE BOX in ('fake','1','2','3') AND day = '2021-07-23' GROUP BY name,day HAVING COUNT(name)>1;` (i even added 'fake' to BOX but it returns me results)

Comment: if you can post some sample output vs expected results that would be helpful

Comment: `...BOX in ('fake', '1', '2' ...` means, that every row where box wich is same as one of the entries in the list ist returned. Please add sample data an expected output so we can better understand your question.